# How do I double click on an image/or link to initiate installation? APPLESCRIPT [Please view image]

Tags: image, automation, click, applescript

I am trying to automate the installation of slack. I run the .dmg then must double click the "Slack" icon to start the install. using the '''click''' function on images is not really doable im guessing.. I see that the URL this image calls on is file:///Volumes/Slack.app/Slack.app/ Do I need to call on this link perhaps ? How can I get the same results of double clicking on the image.

[Accessibility Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3FSJ.jpg)

`tell application "Finder"
    set myFolder to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    open document file "Slack-4.3.3-macOS.dmg" of myFolder
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click image "Slack" of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Slack"
    end tell
end tell`

[Accessibility Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3FSJ.jpg)

Comment: Why not just move the app to the /Applications folder?

Comment: Im trying to automate the install, I dont want the mouse to be invovled. I actually realized I can also run the unix executable located at /Volumes/Slack.app/Slack.app/Contents/MacOS but im having a hard time writing a line to 'do shell script' the file

Comment: How about: `do shell script "cp -R /Volumes/Slack/Slack.app /Applications/"` or if on **macOS Catalina**: `do shell script "cp -R /Volumes/Slack/Slack.app /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/"`

Comment: You are amazing. thank you!

Comment: Guys, im trying to do the same thing with google chrome, issue is there is a space between "google" and "chrome" in the directory. /Volumes/Google Chrome and im getting an error saying directory doesnt exist. I also tired /Volumes/Google%Chrome

Comment: When there are _spaces_ in a _filename/pathname_, you need to either quote it or escape the _spaces_ with a  single backlash if in **Terminal**, or a double-backslash if in a `do shell script` _command_, e.g.,  `do shell script "cp -R '/Volumes/Google Chrome/Google Chrome.app' /Applications/"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in doing this job by clicking the image in AppleScript, you can try code below:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "Finder"
        tell image "Slack.app" of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Slack.app"
            ignoring application responses
                perform action "AXShowMenu"
            end ignoring
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.3
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "Finder"
        tell image "Slack.app" of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Slack.app"
            --key code 125 --also can try use arrow key to select item in context menu
            keystroke "Open"
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I test this code on my MacOS 10.12.6, it works OK. Even though it's easy to use terminal command to do this job, this method involves some very useful AS knowledge point.

1st  : perform action "AXOpen" and "AXShowMenu"

2nd : show context menu and select menu item

3rd  : deal with system delay

If it doesn't have delay issue, you can try the code below, which is more simpler,(also works on my machine):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "Finder"
        tell image "Slack.app" of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Slack.app"
            perform action "AXShowMenu"
            delay 0.3
            keystroke "Open"
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Opened my mind to a whole new way of achieving the goal. Awesome!